# mdns not wait for change but refresh list regularly

Tags: python, python-2.7, mdns

This code below is running all the time and when there is a change in mdns devices, it prints data. 
But I need completely other behaviour. I need to get list of all mdns devices with their data every 100 seconds (so not to wait for change but get whole list at once, then sleep for 100 seconds, and get list again, and again, and again, ...).

How should I edit my code for this behaviour please?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

""" Example of browsing for a service (in this case, HTTP) """

import logging
import socket
import sys
from time import sleep

from zeroconf import ServiceBrowser, ServiceStateChange, Zeroconf


def on_service_state_change(zeroconf, service_type, name, state_change):
    print("Service %s of type %s state changed: %s" % (name, service_type, state_change))

    if state_change is ServiceStateChange.Added:
        info = zeroconf.get_service_info(service_type, name)
        if info:
            print("  Address: %s:%d" % (socket.inet_ntoa(info.address), info.port))
            print("  Weight: %d, priority: %d" % (info.weight, info.priority))
            print("  Server: %s" % (info.server,))
            if info.properties:
                print("  Properties are:")
                for key, value in info.properties.items():
                    print("    %s: %s" % (key, value))
            else:
                print("  No properties")
        else:
            print("  No info")
        print('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        assert sys.argv[1:] == ['--debug']
        logging.getLogger('zeroconf').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    zeroconf = Zeroconf()
    print("\nBrowsing services, press Ctrl-C to exit...\n")
    browser = ServiceBrowser(zeroconf, "_http._tcp.local.", handlers=[on_service_state_change])

    try:
        while True:
            sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        zeroconf.close()
```

Comment: Are you seriously looking for a Python 2 answer? Migrating this code to Python 3 sounds like a good first step in the right general direction.

Comment: yes, I know. I made it for python 2.7. Anyway,if you have code for python 2,  conversion to 3 would be easy. I am sharing my code in answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:
(but I don't like one second sleep function at the bottom - it could cut script runtime and show incomplete list)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

""" Example of browsing for a service (in this case, HTTP) """

import logging
import socket
import sys
from time import sleep
import concurrency

from zeroconf import ServiceBrowser, ServiceStateChange, Zeroconf

def zeroconf_info():
    """zeroconf_info returns a list of tuples of the information about other
    zeroconf services on the local network. It does this by creating a
    zeroconf.ServiceBrowser and spending 0.25 seconds querying the network for
    other services."""
    ret_info = []

    def on_change(zeroconf, service_type, name, state_change):
        if state_change is ServiceStateChange.Added:
            info = zeroconf.get_service_info(service_type, name)
            if info:
                address = "{}".format(socket.inet_ntoa(info.address))
                properties = str(info.properties.items())
                item = (str(info.server), address, info.port, properties)
                ret_info.append(item)

    zc = Zeroconf()
    browser = ServiceBrowser(zc, "_http._tcp.local.", handlers=[on_change])
    sleep(1)
    concurrency.concurrent(lambda: zc.close())()
    return ret_info

print (zeroconf_info())
```